# Анализаторы .pcap файлов

Tags: сеть, wireshark, pcap

Захват трафика с помощью tcpdump`а - вещь замечательная, особенно, когда потом весь захваченный трафик можно посмотреть в удобном представлении. Но обычно в процессе мониторинга сети накапливается огромный массив данных, который приходится, в лучшем случае, разбивать по файлам с ограничением по размеру(дабы потом тот же wireshark не подавился).

Вопрос такой: можете ли подсказать наиболее удобное средство(желательно опенсорсное), которое бы позволяло потом по этим pcap-файлам производить фильтрацию? Т.е применять фильтр сразу к массиву файлов.

P.S Целевая задача - в том, чтобы обеспечить обнаружение специфичных атак. Так что в совершенстве нужно наилучшим образом завернуть трафик через какое-нибудь средство анализа подозрительных пакетов и обнаружения атак.

Answer (score 1):

Snort умеет читать pcap. Через командную строку можно и фильтрануть ...

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать свой фильтр, используя простую библиотеку https://github.com/wkoroy/pcap_file_generator